# Insert the same data in two different tables using yii2:

Tags: yii2

Insert the same data in two different tables using yii2:
Hello,
I am using **yii2**,having two tables **inbox**,**sent_items**.
inbox table contains fields:
**`mail_id (pk), from,to,subject, content,date_time`**.

sent_items table contains fields:
**`mail_id (pk),from,to,subject,content,date_time`**.

i need to insert values through form in two tables in same time.
answer please thanks.

Comment: please visit the following link:https://tahiryasin.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/how-to-save-multiple-related-models-in-yii-complete-solution/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$inbox->load($data)` with data from form and then use 2nd parameter for load function to load same data into another model: `$sent_items->load($data,'Inbox');`